# In the Dutch dates, the month has a period (".") after it

Tags: java, android

my application support dutch dates , i have requested to remove to dot after the month in the date , how can i make sure that there is no dot after the month ?

my code is :

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
Locale local = new Locale("nl-NL");
String monthShortName = time.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,
                Calendar.SHORT, local);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right locale? If I use `Locale local = Locale.forLanguageTag("NL");` there is no dot in the month name...

Comment: @assylias that's interesting, that's a new call to API 21, can you confirm it behaves different to `new Locale("NL")` or `new Locale("nl-NL")`? Maybe the actual strings have changed in 5.0

Comment: @weston I didn't notice the android tag - I was running this on Java SE so the behaviour may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about...

```
monthShortName = monthShortName.replace(".", "");
```

OR (alternate method)

```
String monthShortName = time.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,
            Calendar.SHORT, local).replace(".", "");
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid handling the text after getting the date , hope for a format solution so in all languages it will be the same .

Comment: I added an alternate method to my answer, to perform the replacement directly. But it's more or less the same.